# After I installed HP ALM 11.5 on openSUSE, Jboss do not start successfully

Tags: testing, hp-quality-center

Follow the HP ALM installation guide, step by step. But in the end of installation, start Jboss did not successfully?

Help ! I had tried some solution, reinstall some times, but it failed.

Is anybody can help me? Thx!